# What is the sum of all autocovariances of time series called?

Tags: probability, covariance, time-series

The sum of all autocovariances $\sum_{h=1}^{n} \gamma(h)$ of a weakly stationary time series is a quantity which appears frequently in a project I am working on. I'd like to learn more about it, but in order to do that, I need to know what it's called.